# Pressing arrow keys randomly opens file menu in Scrivener?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

For some reason pressing the <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys to scroll in Scrivener will randomly open the file prompt on my newly bought second hand laptop and I can't work out why. Is this a shortcut or something? The operating system is Windows 10 Pro, and Scrivener is up to date. However, I've a hunch this is Windows or the keyboard and not Scrivener.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be normal: https://howtoscrivener.com/scrivener-keyboard-shortcuts-windows Did you check what key gets pressed when you press up/down on any online website like key-test.ru?